# Calculate Time of each row excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to calculate the times of each Row in Column J and I  i.e. `=J2-I2`
I got some help earlier and wrote up this VBA code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 2 To 1647 / Range("J" & i) - Range("I" & i)
Next i
End Sub
```

and I want it to post the calculation in each row of column K starting with row two the calculation. But I am getting the `method range of object _worksheet failed` error everytime I click the button to run the command. How can I get this error to stop and make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 2 To 1647 Step 1
    Range("K" & i).Value = Range("J" & i).Value - Range("I" & i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

> [For...Next
> statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I tried this code it threw a type mismatch. Is there something I needed to provide that I haven't?

Comment: Ok I see what it is, it's the "K" and the other ones is a string and the i is a integer but I am lost for the love of me on a fix.